# Get Version from binary inside app directory

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a helper tool in my bundle that resides in `Contents/Library/PriviledgedHelperTools` inside my `.app`. Can I somehow read the version of the info.plist of this program?

The Helper Tool itself is NOT a `.app` bundle, it is a binary that is embedded in my `.app` bundle residing in `Contents/Library/PriviledgedHelperTools` which has its `Info.plist` embedded inside of the `__TEXT` section of the binary using the linker flags

```
-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist path/to/info.plist
```

Please note: I am currently not running this program, I just want to check if the currently installed helper tool is older than the one in my bundle and need to check if I have to update the helper tool (e.g. if its comming from a previous version of my program).

Answer (score -1):

Just list all files inside the app dir. There are "version.plist" and "Info.plist" files that you can parse with simple script. If the app has another app inside then its structure is similar to parent.

Comment: That does not work for a helper tool as it is just a binary inside of my `.app` directory in `Contents/Library/PriviledgedHelperTools/binary` which has the `Info.plist` embedded in the `__TEXT` section of the binary. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, got it. Ok, let me think a bit. Did you try some utils like "strings /you/binary/path"? It shows all strings in the binary and one thing you need to do is parse it.